# ASP MVC How to create editor for model which have children elements?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, mapping, viewmodel, children

I'm new in asp.
I must write an application in mvc which have a database where I have a two tables.
One table Parent is realted one to many with table Children.

```
Parent
-------------
parent_id
name


Children
-------------
children_id
parent_id (foreign key)
name
```

When user want to create an element for Parent table, the editor must have an opportunity to add(create) Children.

When user edit Parent then he should have opportunity to delete/edit Children.

There isn't possible to add/edit/delete Children in separete editor

I think I sholuld use a javascript to generate further controls for Child. I can do this but I don't know how to map this html controls to model?

I have wrote this view:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function add_child() {
        $('#children').append($('<input name="child[' + ++$('#children>input').get().length + ']" />'));
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Parent</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>


        <div>Children:</div>
        <div id="children">
            @Html.TextBox("child[1]")
        </div>
        <div>
            <input onclick="add_child()" type="button" />
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

This works fine. But I relly don't know how to map this element on my Parent Model.

Now my Model for create view looks like this:

```
public class ParentModel {
    public ParentModel() {
        Children = //... get all children from database
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    // this should be an ids of selected children
    public string[] SelectedChildren { get; set; }
    // children to display
    public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }

}

public class ChildModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How to fill this Children by the values from view?

Controller:

```
public class ParentController : Controller
{
        // show form
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            ParentModel model = new ParentModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        // Get Parent and Children
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(ParentModel form) {
            // I want to read a form.CreatedChildren
            // but it is Null
            return View();
        }

}
```

**I want to read a form.CreatedChildren but it is Null...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). And the [followup](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) about validation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your model correctly, you need

```
// children to display
public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
```

in your parent model. In your ParentModel constructor

```
Children = new HashSet<ChildModel>();
```

As far as populating the model with data, that belongs in your controller. Something like:

```
var parents = from p in context.ParentModels
              select p;
Return View(parents);
```

Comment: Yes you right that was a misspeled. But that isn't a problem. I have problem in way from view -> model.

Comment: Perhaps posting your controller code would help. Normally, the view would not have anything to do with the model directly. All interaction would happen in the controller.